# C# Dictionary converted with JSON into a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, database, dictionary

I want to store a dictionary in a database, I've already used JSON to serialize the dictionary to `string` and looking for a way to insert the data into a database.

```
string stringDict1, stringDict2l
stringDict1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict1);
stringDict2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict2);
```

Now, deserializing looks like:

```
dict1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(stringDict1);
dict2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(stringDict2);
```

The serialized text looks like:

> "{\"john\":0.2,\"sun\":0.33,\"flower\":0.5, AND SO ON}"

How can I insert those dictioanries into a database and then read from database and deserialize the values using JSON to dictionary again?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("FULL CONNECTION STRING")) // Can also retrieve using ConfigurationManager or WebConfigurationManager
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 (col1) VALUES (@Val1)", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter("@Val1", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        sp.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        sp.Value = var1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(sp);
        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And then something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("FULL CONNECTION STRING"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT col1 FROM table 1", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
        }
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

We use a wrapper class object that handles all of this for us so I'm not 100% on all of this, but gathered this from the various parts of our wrapper class. Should help.

Also, if you wrap it in `using` statements, you generally don't have to worry about remembering to close the connection or dispose of the `SqlCommand` object.

Comment: What is `Val1` and `Var1` and `var` in your example compared to the JSON string? Which values should I put into them?

Comment: The only one you need to worry about, really, is `sp.Value = var1` because `var1` will be your serialized object. I would recommend referring to the link commented by Michael combined with this answer.